# Using csh script to input user specified arguments into a python script

Tags: python, parameter-passing, user-input, csh

Below I have a fairly simple python script that assembles a list of filenames that I will be using another script on. Originally (as can be seen commented out), I had the script cycle through a list of levels in order to populate the list fully. However, I'd prefer that the "user", in this case a CSH script input values into the program, in order to be able to execute my other script on each set of files corresponding to each level before moving onto the next level. Long story short: is there a way to use a CSH script to pass values down into the python program?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
############################################
############################################

levels = raw_input("Enter Levels: ")
#levels = ('1000', '925', '850', '700', '500', '300', '250', '200')
LEVEL = str(levels)
MODEL = "ECMWF"
NX = 360
NY = 181
date = 201409060000
DATE = str(date)
#############################################

FileList = []
data = []


#for (l, item) in enumerate(levels):
# LEVEL = str(item)
  for j in range(24,384,24):
        J = str(j)
        FileList.append([])
        data.append([])
        for i in range(1,51,1):
                data[count-1].append([])
                I = str(i)
                fileName = '/Users/alexg/ECMWF_DATA/'+MODEL+'_'+LEVEL+'_u_'+I+'_FT0'+J+'_'+DATE+'.txt'
                print fileName
                FileList[count-1].append(fileName)
```

(I know the formatting of the code isn't exemplary)

Comment: If you're open to things other than csh, but you can wrap your script in another python script and give it your input with `Popen` and `communicate` from `subprocess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking fore `sys.argv` you can get multiple values from `csh` with adding `sys.argv[1:]` to your source file ! in python we call it [Terminology](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#terminology)

so change this line :

```
levels = raw_input("Enter Levels: ")
```

with :

```
import sys
levels=sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: You might want to add a catch to resort to `raw_input` if no cli args are provided.

Comment: No you dont need 'raw_input' with `sys.argv` we pass values before run the code ! and `levels` should be contain those ! if use `raw_input` you have been not them in `levels` .

Comment: One problem with this method is that it appears it's outputting the user specified level in brackets and quotes within the concatenation. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

i.e, /Users/alexg/ECMWF_DATA/DAT_FILES/ECMWF_['1000']_u_24_FT0360_201409060000.dat 

instead of

/Users/alexg/ECMWF_DATA/DAT_FILES/ECMWF_1000_u_24_FT0360_201409060000.dat

Comment: do you want to concatenate them ?

Comment: I just want the 1000 concatenated inline with the rest of the filename---so no brackets and quotes. can that be done?

Comment: would that be in line with the levels=sys.argv[1:], or is that on a separate line?

Comment: welcome ! you can add it after that line like this `levels=''.join(levels)`

Comment: @Kasra, last question, I promise. Can the join command be used twice in that line? As in, I want to use two (different) inputs on the command line? Currently I have one for level, but i'd like to add another for time.

Comment: @agold2121 welcome :) ... so actually its possible to use 2 `join` but how do you want to get time ?

Comment: id like another command line argument, such as the one for level, so that I can concat the file name with time and level specified by the csh script